# Rails 4: Always use a Postgres function for a certain model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, diacritics

I've got a model `Location` with a field `name` that often contains diacritics - for example "Rhône-Alpes", "Midi-Pyrénées" and "Île-de-France".

This model gets used in a few different ways in my application, particularly for queries by the name. Examples include:

```
Location.find_by(name: 'Rhône-Alpes')
Location.find_or_create_by(name: 'Rhône-Alpes', country: 'France')
```

The arguments to those `find` methods vary across the application. My question is this: how can I make sure that a certain Postgres function (in this case `unaccent()`) is called every time the name field is referred to? This means I can search for 'Rhone' and 'Rhône', and get the same results.

Is it best to override the `find_by` and `find_or_create_by` methods? If so, what's the best way of doing this?

Comment: I might consider storing the unaccented version in a separate column so it can be indexed, and using an unaccented value when searching.

Comment: That would make sense, but it'd be good if I could swap out `unaccent` for some other function (or set of nested functions) in the future, without having to change the contents of an entire column.

Comment: Without knowing what you actually envision needing it's difficult to know how to reply to that. If you want to be able to search using arbitrary combinations of undefined "things" then I'd consider using a more complete searching mechanism like an ElasticSearch etc. When you change how you want to search you'll usually need to concede either re-indexing or re-calculating something.

Comment: Can you try custom finder method with sql in it.

find_by_sql(".... where name= unaccent(val)").where(country: 'france');

Comment: May want to just use where and test for the first in this case.  Location.where('unaccent(name) = ?',nameparam).first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good to push logic down into the database layer, but if you work on lots of different projects all the time, you might need to perform a find without unaccenting in future, then run into problems when you can't easily debug so you must always be careful when doing so.

Do not override the find_by method, this isn't recommended as you may perform a standard find_by and have unforeseen consequences.

Have you considered sanitising the input before the find_by?

```
>> ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate("Rhône-Alpes")
=> "Rhone-Alpes"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you're using **find_by** and **find_or_create_by** when querying by *name*, and you could override those class methods, not exactly sure how to do it the right way, but it should be pretty simple. But why not creating a class method for specifically querying by *name*?, like a scope!. There you could transform both the given *name* as a parameter, and the actual *name* value in the model. Something like this (assuming you have a Ruby method *unaccent* at your disposal)...

```
def self.named(name)
  self.all.select {|location| unaccent(location.name) == unaccent(name) }
end
```

Not sure if it is the answer you're looking for, but it is a way to do it, and you leave this logic in the model layer, independently of the *DBMS* you're using.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

You can create virtual column in DB, like that:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (id SERIAL, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT);

-- create virtual column
CREATE FUNCTION fullname(customer) RETURNS text AS $$
    SELECT $1.firstname || ' ' || $1.lastname
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

INSERT INTO customer VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Mark', 'Pennypincher');

SELECT customer.fullname FROM customer;
```

(stolen from http://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2013.html#April_1_2013 )

Other options is create view for table and wrap column into the function in this view. If you don't try write into virtual column - view is editable.